# Can't use NSMutableArray data after Parsing with NSXMLParser (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsmutablearray, nsxmlparser

Hi I did parsing with NSXMLParser of some xml :

```
<company>
     <name>Idan</name>
     <country>Israel</country>
      .....
     <gender>man</gender>
</company>
```

I see that parsing success , now I have the MutableArray with one object that contain all strings (Idan,Israel etc.) but when I want to use this array, I can't get strings it contain.
When I do :

```
NSMutableArray *use = [pars users ];
        NSLog(@"%@",use );
```

(users it's my array with object) I see:

```
 <List:03f5a78>
```

where List in my code is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface List : NSObject{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *country;
    NSString *status;
    NSString *gender;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *country;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *status;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *gender;
@end

#import "List.h"
@implementation List
@synthesize name,date,city,country,status, gender;
@end
```

I try to do something like this:

```
     NSMutableArray *use = [pars users.name ];
     NSLog(@"%@",use );
```

but is not working, any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Just because the variable "use" is declared as an NSMutableArray doesn't mean it is one.  And it would be helpful to know what kind of object "pars" is, and what the "users" method of it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `description` method of your `List` class, and return a string which includes the values of all of the properties, then output it like you did the first time.  The console will then print the value you returned.

Example:

```
@implementation List

...
...
    -(NSString *)description
    {
        NSMutableString *desc = [NSMutableString string];
        [desc appendFormat:@"name=%@, ", self.name];
        [desc appendFormat:@"country=%@, ", self.country];
        [desc appendFormat:@"status=%@, ", self.status];
        [desc appendFormat:@"gender=%@", self.gender];
        return desc
    }
...
...
@end
```

Comment: Better is to create an NSDictionary with those fields and keys, and then run it through stringWithFormat.  Comes out nicely structured, and easy to maintain.

Comment: I agree if format was important for debugging and I didn't mind checking nil on each property.  The dictionary would be especially useful for huge classes.